# Find a Bigger Number than a number given in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, time-complexity

There is an **UNSORTED** sequence of numbers: `a1,a2,...,an`

And, We Have a number, *i* So We have *ai*

We want to find number, j Which `j<i` and `aj>ai`
Like this:

```
3,4,9,1,8,10,2,2,6,1
if i=8 then j=6
if i=7, j=6 again
if i=10 then j=9
if i=1 then j=NIL (Not In List)
```

Comment: Is this array sorted?

Comment: If the array isn't sorted, I don't see an opportunity for any algorithm to be more efficient than just iterating through the array.

Comment: i'll clarify what @hatchet mean: in order to get sublinear, you'll need to provide some constraints on your problem... e.g the array is sorted, you make many searches of `j` for many `i` on the same array of data, etc...

Comment: Could somebody edit this question to become more clear? I can't understand what it is saying.

Comment: @Tempux done! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do it in O(n) preprocessing and O(log n) per query using a [Segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).

It is very simple to do it in O(log^2 n) per query. First, build a segment tree which supports getting maximum on a segment on O(log n). Second, for each query do a binary search.

I denote `max(a_i, ..., a_j) as max(i, j)`. Say query index is `i`. if `max(i+1, n) <= a_i` then there is obviously no such element. Otherwise you have to find a smallest `j` such that `max(i+1, j) > a_i`, ant this is done with a binary search over `j`.

For further improvement you have do dig into a segment tree structure. I'll give you the basic idea. Assume you have to find first element in the array which is greater than `x`. Initially you are at the root of a segment tree. If the maximum of the left subtree is `> x` then you go to the left subtree, else to the right. It can be easily shown that the leaf where you finish corresponds to the leftmost element of the array which is `> x`.